# Zip4J and Zip Slip vulnerability

Tags: zip4j

Zip4J is listed as vulnerable for [Zip Slip](https://github.com/snyk/zip-slip-vulnerability). They claim that Zip4J 1.3.3 has the fix. However the JAR we download from their [site](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php) is empty and has no classes. 
Did anyone manage to get the 1.3.3 version? Any other alternative for a Zip utility that supports encrypted zips? Have mailed the Zip4J developer, but checking here as well to see how everyone is handling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed there is a problem with the `jar` files from their own website at http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php

But when I downloaded it from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j/1.3.2 , it is working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Wilson. I actually rebuilt the JARs from the source code on github. The mvnrepo is a much better option.

Answer (score 1):

Zip4j 1.3.3 with Zip slip fix is now available on [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have encountered **ZipSlip vulnerability** in your code which supports zip extraction & are searching from fix,

Below solution from Google helped me handle this exploitation(The key is to check for the `canonicalPath` of the file, it must start with your desired destination path in positive case) :

```
val file = File("$destinationFilePath/$filePath")
if (file.canonicalPath.startsWith(File(destinationFilePath).canonicalPath).not()) {
         logger.get().warn(TAG, "Malicious file detected, skipping extracting file ${file.name}")
         return null
 }
```

- Google reference link: https://developer.android.com/topic/security/risks/zip-path-traversal#mitigations

(*In my case I was using [7-Zip-JBinding-4Android](https://github.com/omicronapps/7-Zip-JBinding-4Android) for zip extraction/compression*)